# how to setup StandardSSLContextService for GetSolr

Tags: java, ssl, solr, https, apache-nifi

using **GetSolr** or **InvokeHTTP** to get data from **Solr** databse that secured by **SSL** (**https/self signed**) needs to config "**SSL Context Service**".
how i deal with that? that's needs below [parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id5Bm.png):

```
Keystore Filename:
Keystore Password:
Key Password:
Keystore Type:
Truststore Filename:
Truststore Password:
Truststore Type:
TLS Protocol:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if your Solr is secured with two-way SSL, or one-way SSL...

In Solr is configured for one-way SSL, then you need a truststore that contains the public key of the certificate authority (CA) that was used to create the certificate that Solr is using. You would then create an SSL Context Service using this truststore, which would let NiFi trust Solr.

If Solr is configured for two-way SSL, then you need everything above, but you also need a client certificate for NiFi that was issued from a certificate authority that Solr trusts (likely the same CA that generated Solr's certificate). In this case you would need to provide the keystore and truststore in the SSL Context Service.

Whether or not it is one-way or two-way SSL is most likely based on how Solr was started... in bin/solr.in.sh:

```
SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=false
```

False would be one-way, true would be two-way.

Comment: in my case solr configured for one-way SSL, i export public key and then import it to truststore and put it on nifi "SSL Context Service", everything seems ok but when i run invokehttp processor thats no running up and gives this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWy5i.png)

Comment: Check in nifi-app.log for a more detailed error message with stacktrace, also I think you want to put the public key of the CA into the truststore, not the public key of the solr server itself, it wasn't clear to me which public key you were talking abotu

Comment: there is no CA, it is a self signed solr.

Comment: after i enable "java.arg.16=-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake" in nifi bootstrap i checked log and found this: "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname 10.172.x.x not verified". it seems because of CN and IP's thats are being different? waht i do next? using "keytool -genkeypair  -ext SAN=IP " or what?

Comment: You have to make sure the connections to Solr are being made with the same hostname that is in the certificate... are you using Solr cloud or standalone?

Comment: You will want to specify the hostname for Solr to use when starting each Solr node by passing "-h <your-hostname>" where <your-hostname> is the same as the hostname in the certificate Solr is using.

Comment: my solr is standalone. is there anyway to bypass this context and create a unverified context (because of self signed solr ssl)?

Comment: I don't think there is anyway to bypass this, you just need to make sure that the hostname in Solr's certificate matches the hostname Solr is binding to, and that has to be the same hostname NiFi is connecting to

Comment: I attempted to write up an example showing how to set this up, hopefully this helps https://bryanbende.com/development/2017/10/13/apache-nifi-tls-with-apache-solr